# Downgrade skype on Android to before Microsoft ruined it

Tags: apk, skype, downgrade

I have downloaded a few apk's from APKmirror

removed skype from my Nexus 5x

`adb install -r -d com.skype.raider_7.34.0.114-119668850_minAPI15\(armeabi-v7a\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk 
5486 KB/s (37425319 bytes in 6.661s)
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]`

Is there any way to downgrade without error?  I do not like what Microsoft did to skype at all.

Comment: How did you remove it? Uninstall/reinstall *should* work, with the caveat that you'll lose your app settings.

Comment: I dragged the current Skype to the uninstall icon and it no longer shows up in my app list.  I also did a package search in adb and did not find anything with the word "skype" in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should Uninstall the new version before insalling an old version.

But most companies stop supporting old versions after a major change so it can be possible that after some time MicroSoft decides not to support the version then it will force you to install new version

Comment: how can a company force a new version?  and if so can I trick the old one into installing by modifying the APK?

Comment: @flyingdrifter usually they do it like this. Whenever you will open the app it will only show you to update the app. I have seen this in whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable "install from unknown sources" setting before this works. Also you need to uninstall the latest version first and turn off Google Play autoupdate for this app.

As @deepak pointed out, this may work for sometime until a major change on Skype's backend will start crashing your app or it may start misbehaving.